# How To Call Procedure MySql in Laravel And Pass it to Blade.php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I got problem when i want to call procedure on MySql, this my code

```
 $proc = DB::statement("call ambilKesimpulanLayak ('".$user->dosen->nip."')");
    return view('dosen.data_saya',compact('proc'));
```

when i load data_saya.blade.php it's showing an error like this

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: 
E:\SKRIPSI\Skripsi_AHP\resources\views\dosen\data_saya.blade.php)
```

but i has suplied argument foreach on my blade.php

```
  @foreach ($proc as $p)
   <tr>
   <td>{{$p->nama_jabatan}}</td>
   <td>
   {{$p->kesimpulan}}
   </td>
   </tr>
  @endforeach
```

what's wrong with my code? , Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: First check `dd($proc)`. Is it empty or something else?

Comment: just showing "true" after i do dd($proc)

Comment: Can you please try to execute the same in your MySQL client, like PHPMyAdmin, and check what `call ambilKesimpulanLayak your_value_here` is returning.

Comment: i've try that and no issues with the query

Comment: Try with `DB::select('call ambilKesimpulanLayak($user->dosen->nip)')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Every one this case is has been solved by doing this. Go To `database.php` on `config`
after that search my SQl and Add this code below `options =>`

```
'options' => PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `DB::statement("call ambilKesimpulanLayak ('".$user->dosen->nip."')");`

try `DB::select(DB::raw("call ambilKesimpulanLayak ('".$user->dosen->nip."')"));`